# JavaScript - Create a new variable with the name of a passed in event

Tags: javascript, events, variables, bitmap, createjs

I'm trying to create a new variable with the name of a passed in event, for example:

Say the passed in event

```
event.item.id
```

has the value "bg"

I then would like to create a variable named "bg" for which is to be a Bitmap using CreateJS.

I have tried various things, at the minute I have the following:

```
event.item.id = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
```

However when console logging the variable it comes up as undefined and I can't set anymore values to the variable such as x or y positions.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: This is explained over here pretty well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: Thanks for that - I have followed those instructions however when I later try to do for example `bg.x = 200` I get the error `Cannot set property 'x' of undefined`

Comment: can you post your code in jsfiddle maybe?